# Unable to install postgres 9.1 .. rpm into redhat 6.3

Tags: postgresql-9.1, redhat, rpm

When I try to install the RPM I get the following error:

```
# rpm -ihv ./postgresql91-server-9.1.11-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm 
warning: ./postgresql91-server-9.1.11-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 442df0f8: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
postgresql91 = 9.1.11-1PGDG.rhel6 is needed by postgresql91-server-9.1.11-1PGDG.rhel6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution ..

Downladed the Linux package(postgresql-9.1.11-1-linux-x64.run) from the link below and execute as root,

./postgresql-9.1.11-1-linux-x64.run

All the dependencies are included with this package.

http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload

Answer (score 2):

The database server rpm which you are trying to install has a number of dependencies. While you could install then all manually, by downloading them one at a time and installing them, that's definitely not the easiest way.

I recommended you install it via yum. Full instructions are given on [the postgresql wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation). Yum will handle the task of downloading all the needed rpms and installing them.

Comment: If the repo is added, you can actually install a downloaded RPM with `yum install the-file.rpm` directly, and it'll fetch the dependencies. But why you'd do that when you can just let yum fetch all of it...